# Как изменить свойства содержащие переменную

Tags: sass, scss

требуется что-бы при изменении переменной изменялись также свойства которые используют переменную. Например

```
* {
    margin:0;
}
.button {
    $color:#ffd627;
    border-radius:100vw;
    color:$color;
    border:1px solid $color;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    &.green {
        $color: #46d440;
    }
}
```

На выходе должно получиться

```
* {
  margin: 0; }

.button {
  border-radius: 100vw;
  color: #ffd627;
  border: 1px solid #ffd627;
  padding: 10px 20px; }
.button.green {
  border: 1px solid #46d440;
  color: #46d440;
}
```

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: если честно, не понял вопрос?

Comment: Я очень много думал, но, похоже, таки понял вопрос: вы в `.button.green` переопределили переменную `$color` и хотите, чтобы при этом автоматически поменялся `border`, использующий этот цвет?

Comment: да именно это я и хотел.

Answer (score 0):

Можно осуществить с помощью [миксина](https://codepen.io/kizoso/pen/XzWrOd):

```
@mixin borderAndColor($color)
  color: $color
  border-color: $color

.button
  border-radius: 100vw
  border: 1px solid
  padding: 10px 20px
  @include borderAndColor(purple)
  &.green
    @include borderAndColor(green)
  &.orange
    @include borderAndColor(orange)
  &.red
    @include borderAndColor(red)
```